# What is the “Hello World” problem of Unsupervised Learning?

Tags: unsupervised-learning

As a followup to [this question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/23561/what-is-the-hello-world-problem-of-reinforcement-learning), I'm interested in what the typical "Hello World" problem (first easy example problem) is for unsupervised learning.

A quick Google search didn't find any obvious answers for me.

Comment: Probably knmeans clustering or gaussian clustering

Comment: @FourierFlux Both seem to be solution methods, not problems. Do I understand correctly that problems would be: cluster $n$ training observations in a $d$-dimentsional space, then apply those clusters to new observations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I disagree with the context that MNIST is the "hello world" of supervised learning. It is definitely, though, the "hello world" of **image classification**, which is a very specific sub-field of supervised learning.

I'd consider the [Iris](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/iris) dataset a better candidate for the "hello world" of supervised learning, with other close candidates such as the [Wine](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Wine), [Wisconsin breast cancer](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Breast+Cancer+Wisconsin+%28Diagnostic%29) or [Pima indians](https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/pima-indians-diabetes-database) datasets. However, as an even simpler and more alternative choice, a lot of people prefer generating [their own 2-dimensional datasets](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html) so that can more intuitively understand what the different algorithms are doing. An example of this is [TensorFlow playground](https://playground.tensorflow.org).

Equivalently, in unsupervised learning there are a lot of different tasks. I personally think that **clustering** is probably the task that is easier for people to understand and as such the most common intro to unsupervised learning. Here there are, as well, two options:

- Using an already established dataset, e.g. [Iris](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/iris) (without the labels).
- Generating your own synthetic 2-dimensional data, to better understand how the algorithms work. An example is [this](https://github.com/djib2011/python_ml_tutorial/blob/master/notebooks/26_clustering.ipynb).